# How to get IP s from Chat Applications?

Tags: c#, ip, chat

I am using Windows live and Skype. Is there a way to obtain all the IP addresses of friends in chat applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by sending your friend a file which is big enough (should take atleast 1 minute to transfer, say a ".bmp" file).
While this send in progress, open your command prompt and enter "netstat -n"; there you get that IP address...

Comment: idea s perfect but impractical

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is direct way to find IPs because the person you are chatting will be connected through skype server or windows live server. But you can try this one in command prompt.
type `netstat -n`, it will give you all the foreign connection to your computer. Worth a try.

But you can find IP when receiving email from particular person. Here is [how](http://aruljohn.com/info/howtofindipaddress/).

Just out of curiosity, why the hell you need IP of your contact ?

Comment: because some of my friends saying they are abroad when they chat though most of them are lying

Comment: So why you call liars your friends?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find out using purely the chat application is to use CodeMad's solution, if you had a website you could send them a link and log their ip from there. but just from chat it wouldn't be possible as everything is routed via microsoft/skype

Comment: well eh its impracticable . that is the reason